# Email conversation or threading

Tags: email, smtp, jakarta-mail, imap, mime-types

If A send a mail to B,C, reply for that mail from B is correctly mapped to the mail that is sent by A.  How the mapping of reply and reply all is done internally?  If Retrieval of the mail from inbox and sent items is stored separately in two different tables.  How a reply for that mail can be mapped separately?
If message id for the mail generated is used for mapping, how it is internally done?
Whether retrieval of message id for inbound email can be done and stored in the table?

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.4) explains how the header fields `Message-ID`, `In-Reply-To`, and `References` are used for the purpose of conversation threading. I don't know the implementation details of various mail clients, but maybe you can rephrase your question if some aspects are not clear yet.

Comment: I have learnt message id is generated when a email is sent.  Whether message id is the only way of mapping reply sent for the mail(conversation between sender & receiver)? Retrieval of message id for email that is sent via smtp can be retrieved.  But when the inbox and sent mails are retrieved via coding, whether it is possible to get Message id, reference and other email headers using javax.

Comment: Yes, `Message-ID` is the only reliable way. I'd advise you not to rely on the `Subject` header field or the message body. The `Message-ID` is usually added by the mail client, not the outgoing mail server. Different mail clients generate the unique ID differently. Storing a sent message in a "Sent" folder is a different story altogether (and also usually done by the mail client, not the outgoing mail server). `Message-ID` is a header field just like `Subject`. If you cannot access arbitrary header fields, then use a different/better software library.